# Date Comparison of Two Tables in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I had this Data,

**Table One :**

```
EmpID      Date          Absent
1          01/01/2018    1
1          01/02/2018    1
1          02/05/2018    1
1          03/25/2018    1
1          04/01/2018    0
1          05/02/2018    1
1          06/03/2018    1
```

**Table Two**

```
ID         Amount       DateEffective
1          5.00         02/06/2018
2          3.00         05/02/2018
3          10.00        06/03/2018
```

**Desired Output**

```
EmpID      Month       Year   Absent    Penalty
1          January     2018   2         5.00
1          February    2018   1         5.00
1          March       2018   1         3.00
1          April       2018   0         3.00
1          May         2018   1         13.00
1          June        2018   1         10.00
```

This is my Code

```
SELECT { fn MONTHNAME(one.Date) } AS MonthName, YEAR(one.Date) AS Year, SUM(one.Absent) AS Absent,
    (
        SELECT top 1 two.DailyRate
        FROM table_two as two
        WHERE EmpID = '1'
        AND one.Date <= two.EffectivityDate
    )
FROM     table_one as one
WHERE    EmpID = '1'
GROUP BY { fn MONTHNAME(one.Date) }, MONTH(one.Date), YEAR(one.DTRDate)
ORDER BY Year(one.Date),month(one.Date)
```

and it shows an error :

> Column 'one.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

please help for this issue...
Thanks

Comment: is it a typo error ?  you `GROUP BY` `YEAR(one.DTRDate)` but in the `SELECT` it is `YEAR(one.Date)`

Comment: my mistake... it was one.Date

Comment: how do you calculate the `Penalty` ? Also why are you using ODBC  function { } ? You can use `DATENAME( MONTH, [DATE])` to get the date name

Comment: for sorting January to December

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT   
one.EmpID
,DATENAME(MONTH,one.Date)  AS [MonthName]
,YEAR(one.Date) AS [Year]
,SUM(one.Absent) AS [Absent]
,(SELECT top 1 two.Amount
    FROM table_two as two
    WHERE two.ID =  one.EmpID
    AND YEAR(two.DateEffective) >= YEAR(one.Date)
    AND MONTH(two.DateEffective) >=MONTH(one.Date)
) AS [Penalty]

FROM  table_one as one
WHERE    
   one.EmpID = '1'
GROUP BY one.EmpID,DATENAME(MONTH,one.Date), MONTH(one.Date), YEAR(one.Date)
ORDER BY Year(one.Date),month(one.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding to do this,

```
   select e.EmpID
   ,datename(month,e.Date)[month]
   ,year(e.Date) [year] 
   ,sum(e.Absent) as [Abscount]
   ,a.Amount 
   from 
   empl e  left join abs a 
   on datename(month,e.Date)=DATENAME(month,a.DateEffective)
   group by e.EmpID,DATENAME(MONTH,e.Date), MONTH(e.Date), YEAR(e.Date) , a.Amount
   order by Abscount desc
```

> Revert me if any clarifications needed...

Answer (score 0):

is this helpful.?

```
    Create Table #TabOne(EmpID int,[Date] Date,[Absent] Bit)
    Create Table #TabTwo(ID int,Amount float,DateEffective Date)

    Insert into #TabOne
    SELECT 1,'01/01/2018',1 Union All
    SELECT 1,'01/02/2018',1 Union All
    SELECT 1,'02/05/2018',1 Union All
    SELECT 1,'03/25/2018',1 Union All
    SELECT 1,'04/01/2018',0 Union All
    SELECT 1,'05/02/2018',1 Union All
    SELECT 1,'06/03/2018',1

    Insert into #TabTwo
    Select 1,5.00 ,'02/06/2018' Union All
    Select 2,3.00 ,'05/02/2018' Union All
    Select 3,10.00,'06/03/2018'

    ;with cte1
    As
    (
        Select One.EmpID,MONTH(one.[Date]) As [mon],YEAR(one.[Date]) As [Year],two.Amount,one.[Absent],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by One.EmpID,One.[Date] order by DATEDIFF(dd,two.DateEffective,one.[Date]) desc) as rn
        from #TabOne one
        LEFT JOIN #TabTwo two on one.[Date]<=two.DateEffective
    )

    Select EmpID,DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, [mon]-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))) As [Month],
    [Year],SUM(CASE WHEN [Absent]=0 then 0 ELSE 1 END) As [Absent] ,MAX(Amount) As Penalty
    from cte1 
    where rn=1
    Group by EmpID,[Year],[mon]
    order by EmpID,[Year],[mon]

    Drop Table #TabOne
    Drop Table #TabTwo
```